# Convert class to string

Tags: c#, .net, string, class, casting

So, basicly. I wan't to know if it's possible (if so how), to actually convert a class directly in c# code, to a string? So basicly, everything that is inside that class gets into a string.

That was a little short, but I don't know how to actually say it any more clear than that.

Comment: You want to look into [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx).

Comment: XML serialization tutorial: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

Comment: But it's not a XML document, but a C# Class?

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen Xml Serialization will put the public properties of your class in an XML Format

Comment: The linked question is in Java but might help!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401467/convert-string-into-a-class-object

Comment: I don't know if my question is being read probably. What I mean, is that I want to have my entire class (Every single character no matter what) into a string.

Comment: Without any XML markup or anything.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen - My answer below will do exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serialize it to string you can use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; // To access add reference to System.Web.Extensions


var thing = new Thing();
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(thing);
```

Deserialization process I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19612238/2865050)

Comment: But as I said above in my question. I'm using C#, and I can't seem to get access to the JavaScriptSerializer in Visual Studio.

Comment: Import the `System.Web.Extensions` library into your project.

Comment: I see.. but you didn't really explain how to then actually put it into a string, which was the whole point of the question. I appreciate your help I do!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get every single character of your class, you can't. C# is compiled to [.Net IL Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language). Decompilers like dotPeek or JustDecompile convert the IL back to readable C# code and even if you can do that the code will still not look like the original because the compiler performs optimizations to make it run faster.

But you can use serialization, for example, if you need to send your class across the network or save it to disk. Here is an example of xml serialization:

```
public class Number
{
    public int I { get; set; } 
}
```

---

```
XmlSerializer serializer = 
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(Number));

        Number number = new Number();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder
            = new StringBuilder();

        serializer.Serialize(
            new StringWriter(stringBuilder), number);
```

Correct me if i'm wrong on any of this.