# How to read/save data from/to XML from/to DataGridView (with no DataSource, only columns set by me)?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to make a simple "catalog" application, with a `DataGridView`, where I manually added columns, and an open/save functions.

But everything I found about this is using `DataSources`, thing that I don't want to do, because of its difficulty.

How can I achieve my objective?

---

***EDIT***
I update my question since it's not clear what I want to do.
I want to save data from my DataGridView to a XML file and vice versa, without having to parse every single element of my XML or write this XML file by hand, or similar procedures.
And my "DataSource" field is empty in Visual Studio 2012.
My bad if you haven't understood before :)

Comment: Using the DataSource Property of the Datagridview can actually be fairly easy; I would suggest you create a class that mimics the properties contained in the XML.  Then, you can create a List<customObject>.  You can then set the datasources property equal to the List<customObject>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what exactly you want, but if you have a List containing your class representing the data you can set the DataSource of the DataGridView to this List and the [AutoGenerateColumns property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to true. This will create a column for each public property that your class contains.

Use it like this:

```
myDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
myDataGridView.DataSource = myList;
```

After the user edited the values in the DataGridView you can save your list of class's as a XML file. The part of parsing the XML to a class and vice versa needs to be done manually. If you want a way of how to create this class look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612215/how-to-convert-xml-json-file-to-c-sharp-class)