# Convert XML to classes (deserialize it) and save it into database

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

Hi i have more than 20 links of xml files. I searched a lot to convert my xml to c# and then deserialize it according to classes and then put it into the database but not found a good solution for that. Please help me how to do it.

http://kithnyc.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=60594372&to=9586327751

This is the link of database and some xml is below

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
<url>
<loc>http://kithnyc.com/</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
http://kithnyc.com/products/adidas-originals-nmd-city-sock-black-blue
</loc>
<lastmod>2016-09-12T11:04:04-04:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<image:image>
<image:loc>...</image:loc>
<image:title>adidas Originals NMD City Sock - Black / Blue</image:title>
</image:image>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
http://kithnyc.com/products/kith-logo-mousepad-white
</loc>
<lastmod>2016-12-23T00:01:41-05:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<image:image>
<image:loc>
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0094/2252/products/20150810-_MG_2963.jpg?v=1482353363
</image:loc>
<image:title>Kith Logo Mousepad - White</image:title>
</image:image>
</url>
</urlset>
```

This is the xml i want to put all its nodes in the database like "Loc" , "lastmod" and "changefreq" etc. Please help me how to convert it into classes and then how to deserialize it. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19612238/87956 to convert xml to class and then use normal serialization/deserilization to save and retrive as object from database. Also since you are compiling into cs which means you have concrete structure you may consider creating seperate table for xml in question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it like this:

Step 1: Read the file by the below line

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filebyte);
```

Step 2: The get all node of xml by Descendants method and convert it into list.
if need apply where clause to filter that data.

```
var pNodelist = xdoc.Root.Descendants().ToList().Where(i => i.Name.LocalName == "p");
```

Step 3: Create data table and store all the data in data table from list like

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("StartTime");
dt.Columns.Add("EndTime");
dt.Columns.Add("Message");
foreach (var data in pNodelist)
{
if (data.HasAttributes == true)
dt.Rows.Add(data.FirstAttribute.Value, data.LastAttribute.Value, data.Value);
}
```

Step 4 : Then you can save it db and you can avoid the step 4 and directly store date from list to data base

Comment: Anurag can you please brief on what is "P" here i.Name.LocalName == "p");

Comment: @Arslan Ahmad  p is the paragraph tags in my Xml  as i want all the p tags

Comment: @ArslanAhmad you use simple Descendants() to get all nodes.

Comment: i can show all of the data in xml file but all the data is row wise mean all the nodes are on the same row. I want to seperate it like Loc, changefreq etc. And how to show the data in data table. I am new so if you can help to show the table according to their nodes will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can add following data classes and repository class in your code.You can just call Repository class with filepath and call its FindAll method.It returns Url list.

```
 public class Url
{
    public string Loc { get; set; }
    public string Changefreq { get; set; }
    public string Lastmod { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }

}
public class Image
{
    public string Loc { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
    public class Repository
{
    private XDocument xmlDatas;
    public Repository(string filePath)
    {
        xmlDatas = XDocument.Load(filePath);
    }
    public List<Url> FindAll()
    {
        return xmlDatas.Elements().Elements()
            .Select(url =>
            {
                Url data = new Url();
                foreach (var item in url.Elements())
                {
                    switch (item.Name.LocalName)
                    {
                        case "loc":
                            data.Loc = item.Value;
                            break;
                        case "changefreq":
                            data.Changefreq = item.Value;
                            break;
                        case "lastmod":
                            data.Lastmod = item.Value;
                            break;
                        case "image":
                            Image image = new Image();
                            foreach (var img in item.Elements())
                            {
                                switch (img.Name.LocalName)
                                {
                                    case "loc":
                                        image.Loc = img.Value;
                                        break;
                                    case "title":
                                        image.Title = image.Title;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            data.Image = image;
                            break;
                    }
                    var s = item.Name.LocalName;
                }
                return data;
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked it that Findall() function is not returning any thing please check that   Repository a = new Repository("http://kithnyc.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=60594372&to=9586327751");
            
            List<Url> s = a.FindAll();

Comment: I changed the repository class.It is ok now

Comment: Thanks a lot Mehmet. You are genius.. Thanks for your kind help

Comment: No problem.It is pleasure to help someone.If he is Muslim ,it is better